# How to consolidate 10+ Tables into one, in chronological order?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good evening!

I am constructing a portfolio and I want to automatically consider my paid dividends in my cash balance. I have an online source feeding all the dividend information into my sheet. I've created excel tables for each stock (currently 14, and will be continually increasing) with identical headers: Symbol, Date, Quantity & Div/Share.

I need to consolidate these into one table, chronologically (with duplicate dates). I'm currently a little stuck, I ideally wanted an excel only solution but begin to realize it might not be possible due to the number of tables I have. I tried the pivot table route but I'm having issues outputting it in the same fashion.

What would be the best way to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Here are some screenshots:

[Desired output for Dividend History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4NUK.png)

[Some of the 14 stock dividend tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2IKX.png)

Comment: Please write me that simply you want to merge many table into one sheet in order or want to perform Consolidation with other function like SUM to combine many table data into ONE.

Comment: This could be done with a pretty simple formula if your stock dividend tables were arranged vertically.  That would put all the dates and dividends in their own column.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: Your probably better off putting all the data into a database, and in your case access.  Then you can have queries like "select symbol,currency,date,quantity,DivShare, (DivShare*quantity) as "Dividend Amount" from stocks order by date;"   Obviously you could have DividendAmount as a separate column instead of computed if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2010 or newer version **Power Query** may help you. It is Microsoft's own product if you haven't heard of. You can merge your tables and play along with them by many means. Here are two links that hope that may help:

[Power Query 101](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/power-query-basics/)

[Merge Sheets/Tables](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-combine-data-from-multiple-sheets/)

Comment: Thank you Fezzik, I was able to complete everything very easily with the links provided. Power Query is quite something, I definitely love how functional it is.